# Invalid XPATH Expression in Selenium/JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, xml, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This may be stupid but I am getting this error: `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id='container']/article[4]/div/p/a/*[text()[normalize-space(.)='Silver']' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Here is my xpath: `"//*[@id='container']/article["+i+"]/div/p/a/*[text()[normalize-space(.)='"+color+"']"`

Thanks, Ben!

Comment: You should share relevant HTML block of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**/*[text()[normalize-space(.)='Silver']** is not a valid syntax,

Can you try with 
/*[normalize-space(text())='Silver']

Recheck your xpath in firepath as a validation before execution, Red colour indicates wrong syntax, xpath provided by you is as below in firepath validation

[image]

Update your xpath to make it valid

[image]

Or use Contains in your text field

```
//*[@id='container']/article[4]/div/p/a/*[contains(text(),'Silver')]
```

Hope this helps!!